# How can I implement rank over division operation in cakephp query builder for 2 column?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I am trying to get rank over from order by 2 column on division result. Example I have total get_count and total members. I am trying to rank it by `team_members/team_get_count` ASC order.

```
->select([
      'team_members' => $query->func()->count('TeamsUsers.user_id'),
      'team_get_count' => $this->find()->func()->coalesce([$query->func()->sum('SummaryCoins.get_count'), 0],[null, 'integer']),
      'ranking'=> RANK() OVER(ORDER BY (coalesce(SUM(SummaryCoins.get_count),0)/coalesce(COUNT(TeamsUsers.user_id),1)) DESC),  <--- Trying to implement this line using cakephp.
])
```

Comment: And what _exactly_ are you having problems with? Have you read the docs on [**how to build window function expressions**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#window-functions)? btw, without `ORDER BY` clause your example is invalid SQL. Also are you using a DBMS that supports referencing aggregates from the select list (IIRC only MySQL allows that)?

Comment: @ndm database here postgres. I have given only selection part from my query. RANK() and Over and Division among I am trying to apply.

Comment: OK, so your query will probably fail with Postgres, as you cannot reference those aggregates. Anyhow, I'm still unsure what exactly you're struggling with, programming-wise?

Comment: @ndm I am actually trying to implement below line in cakephp 
'ranking'=>'RANK() OVER( ORDER BY ( coalesce( SUM(SummaryCoins.get_count),0 ) ) DESC )',

I have updated my question.

Comment: @ndm I have again update with division.